# Admin page not loading in Django

Tags: django

I have a new app, which works fine, i can load all my new pages and navigate without any problem. But when i try to access the admin dashboard, i have an error 500. I am new to Django (from Railsd) and would appreciate some help, as i do not see any error log.
My setup is as follow:

**Settings.Py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangoformsetjs',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_hosts',
    'rest_framework',
    'djoser',
    'app'  # Enable the inner app 
]


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
)
```

**core/url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/app', include('app.urls')),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("authentication.urls")),  # add this
    path("", include("app.urls"))  # add this
]
```

I was told to check the setup of the admin using : django-admin check,
But i get the following error:

```
   raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

This is a bit overwhelming given that i was super comfortable in my previous language. Can you guys help me understand please ?
(i am using a template)

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot ??

Comment: can u check if this line is present in ur asgi.py and wsgi.py `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<urapp>.settings')`